# pulling more than one value with re

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like help with `re` in Python3 in the case of pulling more than one value with a compile.

**Value:**

```
[+] Name: Responsy-v4-0-3 - v4.0.3
[+] Name: add-to-any - v1.5.8
[+] Name: captcha - v4.1.3
[+] Name: wordpress-popular-posts - v3.2.3  `
```

I tried the following:

```
re.compile('Name: (. *) -')
```

It returned `"Responsy-v4-0-3"`, how can I get the rest?

Comment: What? What's the output you get, and what were you expecting instead? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over line by line and then apply the regex on each line. OR simply use the above regex in `re.findall` function.

**Example:**

```
>>> s = '''[+] Name: Responsy-v4-0-3 - v4.0.3
[+] Name: add-to-any - v1.5.8
[+] Name: captcha - v4.1.3
[+] Name: wordpress-popular-posts - v3.2.3'''
>>> re.findall(r'Name: (.*) -', s)
['Responsy-v4-0-3', 'add-to-any', 'captcha', 'wordpress-popular-posts']
```

Comment: Ok, it worked.
And I was testing this site here https://regex101.com/#python so that it only takes the first value.
Thank you!

Comment: add `g` modifier in that.